# How to Resize an image on an Image Control?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, win-universal-app

I’m trying to resize an image on a [UWP Image control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) (XAML) using

```
ScaleTransform t = (ScaleTransform)image.RenderTransform;
```

But am getting an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.MatrixTransform'
>   to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ScaleTransform'.

So how *do* I resize it (not using the `Stretch` property)?

Comment: What is "Universal Windows Image" ?

Comment: @DaveInCaz I meant an image that's shown on a UWP Image control. Edited now and included a link to the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a new ScaleTransform to the `RenderTransform` property once:

```
image.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
```

Now you can later safely access it by

```
var t = (ScaleTransform)image.RenderTransform
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way of _getting_ the image's size (Not the Control's size)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You are setting the Image control's Source property to something, e.g. a BitmapImage that has Width and Height properties.

Comment: I'm setting the `Source` property to a path of a file. I assume that file is read and stored in some Bitmap somewhere. Is there a way of getting it in code?

Comment: Get the Source property in code behind. It should be a BitmapImage (so you can cast it to type BitmapImage), which has PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties.

Answer (score 3):

The existing RenderTransform is of type MatrixTransform which cannot be cast to a ScaleTransform.

You can either replace the existing MatrixTransform with a new ScaleTransform:

```
image.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(2, 2);
```

or you can update the existing MatrixTransform with the desired scale:

```
(image.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform).Matrix = new MatrixTransform(2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I now understand this better.